# Background UIViewController loading when ModalViewController is in the foreground (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm not sure why this is happening, but in the App delegate, I'm setting a viewcontroller as the root and presenting a ModalViewController in front of it. The strange thing is that the viewcontroller behind the modalviewcontroller is still loading even though it does not appear. Is this normal? Is there a way to prevent the viewcontroller behind the modalviewcontroller to load?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by "loading."  As long as the view controller in the background is the parent view controller of the modal view controller, it is going to need be initialized before the modal view controller can be displayed at all.  In that sense, it must be loaded.

If, on the other hand, you mean that the contents of the background view controller are visually displayed and then, afterwards, the model view controller appears on top of it—but you don't want the contents of the background controller to be seen until after the modal view controller is dismissed—then one possibility would be to set the `hidden` property to `YES` and unhide the contents when modal view controller is dismissed.  To do that, I would make the background view controller a delegate of the modal view controller, so it receives a callback when the modal view controller is dismissed.

Comment: By loaded i mean loadView is called (it is not displayed visually). So by your answer it appears this is normal. The problem is that I'm using the modal view as a login page and the view controller behind it loads data based on the logged in user. Since the data loading is done automatically when the view is loaded, it crashes since no user is logged in. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Move the code to load to the data into an "update" method.  Check if the user is logged in before calling this update method when the viewController is loaded so that the application does not crash when it tries to load the data before logging in.  Create a callback method on the background view controller which is called when a login is successful.  Call the update method inside of this callback back method.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a way to prevent the view from loading but even if there is it'll ad more complexity than anything else. Thanks a bunch!